# GIMP adding border upon printing

Tags: gimp

I have a image on gimp I am trying to print, The canvas size is A4 and should be printing correctly.

However when clicking print, noticeable borders (about 10px) appear on each side. I have checked the edges of the images and they go to the edges of the canvas.

Is there a way to disable these borders?

Answer (score 1):

All printers have a minimum margin size. If your picture goes further, the image is either scaled or trimmed.

Maybe what you need is an **offset printer**, or print your image on a bigger paper and then cut it down to the A4 size. Also note that not all convertions between *computer dimensions* and *real dimensions* are perfect, unless you have the right equipment of course.

Comment: When exported as a png, The image can then be printed properly. However printing direct from gimp provided me with better quality and faster performance than printing from the png. However left a border.

Comment: Have you tried exporting it as a PDF (with lossless compression or not image compression at all) and printing it from another app (like evince)? Also check the exported PDF to see if the image aligns with the borders, it may be an issue with GIMP misusing/misreading the border information from the printer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems THE ONLY possible answer to the problem, because it is simply a years long bug in Gimp (or GTK, it relies on). Gimp's Unix nature just makes its printing through GTK not fully compatible with Windows.

It is discussed here, and I welcome you to make more votes there for raising the priority: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/8250

That is how GIMP communicates with printer drivers under windows. Kind of platform-dependent bug. It depends on your printer brand, and their culture of making drivers. For instance, with Epson I have no problem with borders (when there is a "no-borders" option in the driver available); and with PostScript office modular laser-printers there are is no problems of selecting the paper size. But with Brother inkjet printer Gimp always produces borders regardless of the "no-borders" option. And it refuses selecting certain paper formats, even those standard formats available in the driver. Meanwhile other native Windows applications like Paint.NET print without borders. We should emphasize this problem in the bug-tracker, so the developers make a time on rewriting the print-out code for Windows (it should be rewritten completely!)